# JDBC profiling tools

Tags: java, jdbc, profiling

We need to profile the JDBC operations of several web applications, number of queries, time spent, rows returned, ...

Have you used any free/commercial JDBC profiling tool? What are your experiences?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used it but have come across [Elvyx](http://elvyx.sourceforge.net/index.html). Again it has not been updated recently.

Answer (score 4):

Now VisualVM supports JDBC profiling as well.
Just have a look
https://visualvm.github.io/download.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only JDBC profiling tool that I know is [P6Spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/). Ancient but still works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JAMon (Java Application Monitor)](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) too. Also older, but works.

Answer (score 1):

[`IntelliJ IDEA`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has a plugin called [`Fluid`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8456?pr=idea) for `HTTP` and `JDBC` libraries. It seems to be actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JDBC profiler built in a JProfiler (go to Hotspots view -> JDBC), best thing I've seen so far...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jdbc spy: https://github.com/lbaeumer/jdbcspy.
It can be configured very easily and will provide information, which statements are executed, what are the statements with the longest duration, additional statistics about your connections, what statements are executed how often, etc.